# How can I use same MongoDb pipeline for two queries with common first stage?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have 2 queries which I use the aggregate()  pipeline

1. [filter,sort1,A,B,C]
2. [filter,sort2,a,b,c]

Is it possible that I use the first stage of the pipeline for both the queries? It will also make the two queries transactional if the first stage is common.

I am using the aggregate() function and 4 stages. Similarly, I have 1 more query where I just have to get an aggregate count after the initial filter.

I want both the queries to have consistent data as my database is updating quickly. So I would want to use only 1 pipeline initially for the first stage.

```py
collection.aggregate([initialFilter,sortInitial,group,sortFinal])
```

I am using pymongo client.

Also how to make 2 queries transactional/atomic in pymongo?

Comment: It's pretty unclear how your code looks like, could you give us some hint?

Comment: If the size of the final result of both queries is not too large, you might want to try [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

Comment: @thammada thanks! $facet actually worked for my use case ! All I wanted is to have the same set of documents for the two querries (consistency) which is what exactly $facet does for multiple pipelines. I wished there was to merge pipelines (Like using a part of the pipeline common. For example, using the initial filter common in my case)